# Why time became faster after measured several elapsed time in a loop using System.nanoTime() at Java

Tags: java, loops, runtime, elapsed

i am using System.nanoTime() to measure elapsed time or runtime in java. But in this case, i tried to measure several elapsed time using a loop. But, every time the loop is continues, the time became faster. While i expecting the values to be close each other. Here i attach my code.

```
int dataSize = 6, popSize = 20, maxGen = 200;
double pc = 0.5, pm = 0.05;
double[] time = new double[testsample];
double start, end;
data = inisiasiData(dataSize);

for (int i = 0; i < testsample; i++) {

    start = System.nanoTime();
    Genetic_Controller gc = new Genetic_Controller(popSize, pc, pm, maxGen);
    gc.goOptimise(data, dataSize, hybrid);
    System.out.println(gc.getOptimumPrice() + " ");
    end = System.nanoTime();
    time[i] = (end - start) / 1000000;

   }

   System.out.println();
   for (int i = 0; i < testsample; i++) {
        System.out.println(time[i]+" ms");
   }
```

And below is the result ( 3 time test ).

```
Test 1 :

173 
173 
173 
173 
173 
173 
237 
173 
214 
173 

14.216628 ms
4.589741 ms
2.873837 ms
3.148624 ms
3.2326 ms
2.918157 ms
2.704486 ms
1.832538 ms
1.579211 ms
1.588542 ms
===================================================================
Test 2 :
173 
173 
173 
293 
173 
173 
173 
274 
173 
173 

1.976229 ms
1.296026 ms
2.476351 ms
2.294404 ms
2.714749 ms
2.268745 ms
2.263146 ms
2.18057 ms
2.282274 ms
2.313999 ms
===============================================================
Test 3 :
173 
213 
173 
173 
173 
173 
173 
173 
173 
173 

1.982294 ms
1.468642 ms
1.143003 ms
1.135072 ms
1.153266 ms 
1.239109 ms
1.185925 ms
1.00351 ms
0.977851 ms
1.044565 ms
```

Your help means a lot to me. Thanks.

Comment: It's probably because of JVM warm-up. Check Rule#1 on the first answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: i'm sorry sir, i'm not to involved in JVM, i just a newbie. Can you give me more detail answer ? thank you very much.

Comment: There's a detailed answer at the link given above. Take a look through the answers and you'll understand